# While Record with JMeter in .Net Application, Popup is not displaying

Tags: jmeter

My application is developed in .NET, When i Record with Jmeter, Application is not displaying a popup after click Submit button on the page. it is recording all the other action. But after click a popup window is expecting which is not displaying

Step 1. Login application
Step 2. Input some data and click on Submit 
Step 3. A popup should display which is not comming while record

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is very good, but in some cases it behaves odd.

Consider the following alternative methods of recording a scenario:

1. Use [JMeter Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) - no proxies, no SSL certificates, no extra configuration.
2. Use [Badboy](http://www.badboy.com.au/recording.html) recording functionality - Badboy has an option to export recorded script into a JMeter .jmx file
3. Use external proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) in combination with [online network dumps to JMeter scripts converter](http://converter.blazemeter.com/)